# Adding all users to a AD group excluding a few ones using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I have this doubt,

have to add every user in active directory to a group, but there are a few ones who dosen't have to be in this group,

I already know the information of this set of discriminated users..

so, there is a way to do a powershell command where i spicify this set of user  and every user that dosen't match with this set would be added to the group?

i'm making a csv file whe is all the users by SamAccountName

```
Get-AdUser -Filter * | Select SamAccountName | Export-CSV c:\List.csv
```

, so i can add a second column with the name of the group, after that i was thinking to add a where clause in powershell to compare the SamAccountName with another csv with the set of discriminated users, but i don't know if that would work...

There is a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd create a flat array with the exclusion then use it in the Where clause.

Something like:

```
$ExcludedUsers =
@(
    "user1"
    "user2"
    #...
)

$GroupMembers = Get-AdUser -Filter * | Where-Object{ $ExcludedUsers -notcontains $_.samAccountName} 
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity <GroupName> -Members $GroupMembers
```

If you are extracting the exclusions from a csv file you can use something like:

```
$ExcludedUsers = ( Import-Csv C:\ExcludedUsers.csv ).samAccountName
$GroupMembers  = Get-AdUser -Filter * | Where-Object{ $ExcludedUsers -notcontains $_.samAccountName} 
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity <GroupName> -Members $GroupMembers
```

Comment: it works, it works so smooth, in the $GroupMembers line it was a missing ) and that's everything i can add, thanks a lot Steven, u r great.. hope you are having a nice quarantine <3

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out.  I edited the answer.  You don't need to wrap it in ().

Answer (score 0):

```
$ExcludedUsers = @()
import-csv C:\ExcludedUsers.csv | ForEach-Object { $ExcludedUsers += $_.SamAccountName}

$GroupMembers = (Get-AdUser -Filter * | Where-Object{ $ExcludedUsers -notcontains $_.samAccountName})

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity GroupName -Members $GroupMembers
```

that's the code i use, if that helps anyone in the future.
thanks to Steve.

Comment: Can you show whatever lines of code you may have in front of the first line and behind the last line, or is that it?

Comment: Don't use `+=` in this way. It's unnecessary and a bad habit.  Using it on arrays causes a recreate & copy.  Over large sets this causes significant performance degradation.  In this case you can use automatic unrolling to extract the samAccountName to an array. It would look like: `$ExcludedUsers = ( import-csv C:\ExcludedUsers.csv ).SamAccountName`. Auto-Unroll was introduced in PoSh 3, but even without it you don't need +=.  This is equivalent: `$ExcludedUsers = Import-Csv C:\ExcludedUsers.csv | ForEach{ $_.samAccountName }` . But, you can see Auto-Unroll is more succinct.

Comment: I updatyed the answer with the alternate approach.